# How can I edit Books’ metadata on iOS?

Tags: ios, pdf, filesystem, books, metadata

On iPhone SE 2 running iOS 16.6.1, there is no feature to edit the “Author” field in the Books app, for PDFs.

[image]
[image]
[image]

There is no feature to edit the metadata of files in the Files app either:

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2):

iOS is sandboxed, and the Books app does not save data to a folder in the Files app, so there is no iOS SDK function to access or modify the Books app’s files. This determines that you must copy the PDF out of the Books app via the Share menu to somewhere else to modify the metadata, and then import it back in.

There are plenty of ways to edit that metadata once it is somewhere else than Books, but that is a separate, wide topic.

There is some hope for automation using Shortcuts to pass the PDF file somewhere and then open it in Books.

You can also edit the file on your computer and turn on the Books app’s Sync with iCloud setting.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the app Calibre can do the editing, once the books are extracted from the Books app as mentioned above.

https://calibre-ebook.com

Comment: that might work better as an edit to the other answer.

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit beyond the immediate scope of this question, but I ended up with the following in a similar situation recently, and I'm still amused that it actually works. [image]

Comment: I love that. A true hack!